# Scroll textbox to the bottom automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm with TextBox and a vertical scrollbar. Text is appended to the textbox in the following way:

```
 UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & "**Opened file " & i & "**" & vbNewLine
```

When there is too much text to show, the scrollbar doesn't scroll down to show the added text. I need to see that text in the process of the macro running.

I tried

```
UserForm1.TextBox1.CurLine = -1
```

and

```
UserForm1.TextBox1.CurLine = UserForm1.TextBox1.LineCount-1
```

Comment: Here is the answered question [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608631/6648862 ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608631/6648862)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto scroll to bottom with a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607344/auto-scroll-to-bottom-with-a-textbox)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer from

[Auto scroll to bottom with a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607344/auto-scroll-to-bottom-with-a-textbox/6608631#6608631)

```
AppendText "Bla de bla bla."



sub AppendText(strText As String)
    with txtStatus
        .setfocus '//required
        .value = .value & strText & vbNewLine
        .selstart = len(.Value)
    end with
end sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried all and wasted lot of time and tried almost everything, till come across this, somewhere over the Internet:

```
.HideSelection = False
```

And that worked! Hope that will help to someone as well...